# Why でも is used rather than も in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, particle-でも

> もし時間がないなら、明日**でもいい**よ。

Why is the particle で used? With time expressions the で particle expresses time limit. So it's weird to see the で with 明日. 明日もいいよ seems better(?). でも here can be the "even though/even/but" meaning. But も sounds better(?).

Comment: You should look up でも in the dictionary. This is not で + も、 nor is it でも _'but'_ but it's でも _'or something'_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to think of it, which I found in the Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar, is:

### でも ＝ て-form of です/だ ＋ も

＝　verb meaning “to be”　＋　particle meaning “even”*

**〜でもいい is the です/だ version of the grammatical pattern 〜てもいい**, which we use when asking for permission to do things. By putting the verb です/だ in its て-form, we can then ask if the thing itself (a noun) is permissible.

- お手洗い行っ**てもいい**ですか？/ May I go to the bathroom? [literally: Is even going to the bathroom OK?]
- お手洗い**でもいい**ですか？/ Is the bathroom OK?
  [literally: Is even it being the bathroom OK?]
  You’d say this if you’re doing something and asking if it’s OK to do it in the bathroom.

I recently wrote a blog post on this actually! [Rescheduling appointments without sounding like a jerk… 〜でも…?](https://francesthinks.com/2016/09/16/slap-3-rescheduling-appointments-without-sounding-like-a-jerk-%E3%80%9C%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82%E3%81%84%E3%81%84%EF%BC%9F/)

Answer (score 5):

I feel that, this use case of でも is an abbreviated form of であっても。
(Note, I recognize there exist those uses of でも which do not fall into this category.)

So in here, もし時間がないなら、明日でもいいよ。 is an abbreviated (or colloquial) form of もし時間がないなら、明日であってもいいよ。 which translates to:

```
If no time, it is OK to be tomorrow.
```

Or something like that.

---

Please note that this is based on my recognition so when speaking in terms of Japanese strict grammar, it may not be precise.

Comment: Is it possible for the inclusive particle も to go after the て form of a verb? Is it similar with verb + の/こと + も?

Comment: @Dekiru Could you give me some example you have in mind?  I currently don't understand what would be an example for "て form of a verb" would be like.

Comment: "て form of a verb"は「動詞のて形」、「走って」とか「食べて」とかの形です。多分、回答の「明日であっても」の「あって」が、動詞「ある」の「て形」だから、「動詞のて形のあとに「も」を使ってもいいの？それって「する＋の＋も」「する＋こと＋も」と似たもの？」って聞いておられるのだと思います。

Comment: @Dekiru Now I understand your question.  Thanks to chocolate. In short, for example, 「食べてもいいよ」 sounds valid Japanese, so I think answer would be yes.  About verb + の/こと + も、 I'm not really sure.  (Think that should be another question, IMHO..)

Comment: A:私は食べることが大好きだが、外に行くことも大好きのですよ。Is this 行くことも the same with 行っても? Can I replace the であって above with であること and still yield the same meaning? Because it seems that であって acts like a(n) noun/object. I have never seen the "て form of the verb" followed by も so I was surprised. Does A's statement here is grammatically correct, especially in deciding whether は or が is used?