# What exactly happens when you embed a clause with も?

Tags: particle-も

I understand what's going on when you embed a interrogative clause using か、like when you form pronouns like 誰か、or write things like 「ええ、何を食べたか知らないよ・・・。」

However, It's still beyond me what も、does when used to embed a clause; I get how 誰か means 'somebody' or 'whom', but I don't understand why what's normally the temporally inclusive topic marking particle makes it's 誰も mean 'everyone' or 'anyone', which is what I'm hoping to learn.

Edit: Could you also explain how the meaning changes when using でも instead of using も？

Comment: 誰 isn't a clause

Comment: @Tirous https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/39825/7810

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Words like 誰も and 何も etc. when used with negative verbs take on their negative counterpart essentially.

誰かいた　**Someone** was there.

誰もいなかった　**No one** was there. (There wasn't anyone there)

For the most part the でも just sort of emphasizes it in a the sense:

それは有名でもない　That is not *even* famous.

It's actually just the same particle も attached to the particle で (or also the copula だ in て form)